# General error: PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS cannot be used with persistent PDO instances

Tags: laravel, postgresql, pdo, persistence, laravel-10

I am using laravel 10 and PostgreSQL 12.15 (Debian 12.15-1.pgdg120+1).

It takes some time to make new connection for each request so keeping the connection alive should make requests faster. Hence I added `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,` in `pgsql` connection.

my `database.php` looks like :

```
'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'search_path' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'disable',
            'options' => [
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            ],
        ],
```

When I execute php artisan db:migrate, it gives below error.

```
PDOException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS cannot be used with persistent PDO instances

  at vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:210
    206▕                 throw Exception::invalidPdoInstance();
    207▕             }
    208▕ 
    209▕             $this->_conn = $params['pdo'];
  ➜ 210▕             $this->_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, [PDODriverStatement::class, []]);
    211▕             unset($this->params['pdo']);
    212▕         }
    213▕ 
    214▕         if (isset($params['platform'])) {

      +10 vendor frames 
  11  database/migrations/2023_07_07_055322_modify_reports_table.php:34
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()
```

Is it advisable to unset PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS while connecting database? I want to use persistence connection. I am not using any custom statement class.

Does anyone has experienced this issue and can help with the solution?

Comment: looks like you need to update Doctrine

Comment: It seems working after updating doctrine/dbal

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got this error, when I had laravel/homestead version 14.0.2 installed, why the code supported 8.2.1.

Downgrading the vagrant -box fixed the issue for me. So it's releated to doctrine/dbal either to newer or older version.

Command to find out your vagrant box -version is:

```
 vagrant box list
```

If you are working at phz.fi, you can run:

```
 vagrant box remove --provider=virtualbox --box-version=14.0.2 laravel/homestead
  ./down.sh && ./up.sh
```